# Downvotes after answer deleted?

Tags: support, down-votes

I realized that I gave an incorrect answer to a question just now and deleted my answer while working on a revision.  The votes for that answer showed as 0 on my screen while editing (and the answer clearly showed as deleted).  When I undeleted the revised answer, I saw that I had a score of -2, and upon refreshing within a few seconds, -3.

Is this intended behavior?

Comment: The downvotes were cast before the question was deleted, or just after it was undeleted. You just didn't refresh the page quickly enough. There is a *lot* of traffic on Stack Overflow...

Comment: @Cody: Does that mean downvotes are queued?  Once the page was refreshed, it still showed 0.

Comment: I don't understand how your question can say that the score changed, but your comment says that after the page was refreshed, the score was still 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleted questions cannot be voted on. What you saw is because your browser's cache is not updated. Lately, for example, I have noticed that I must empty the Safari 5.1 cache after asking a question; differently, I am not able to see my question in the list of the questions, ordered by those most recently asked.
I didn't check all of the SE sites, but in some of them the problem seems to appear more frequently.